# How to keep only numbers and some special characters in a string?

Tags: c#, regex, string

I have a string containing regular characters, special characters and numbers. I'm trying to remove the regular characters, just keeping the numbers and the special characters. I use a loop to check if a character is a special character or a number. Then, I replace it with an empty string. However, this doesn't seem to work because I get an error "can't apply != to string or char". My code is below. If possible, please give me some ideas to fix this. Thanks.

```
public string convert_string_to_no(string val)
{
    string str_val = "";
    int val_len = val.Length;
    for (int i = 0; i < val_len; i++)
    {
        char myChar = Convert.ToChar(val.Substring(i, 1));
        if ((char.IsDigit(myChar) == false) && (myChar != "-"))
        {
             str_val = str_val.replace(str_val.substring(i,1),"");
        }
    }
    return str_val;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use regular expressions to do that.its faster than using loop and clean

```
    String test ="Q1W2-hjkxas1-EE3R4-5T";
    Regex rgx = new Regex("[^0-9-]");
    Console.WriteLine(rgx.Replace(test, ""));
```

check the working code [here](http://ideone.com/XZkmiL)

Comment: This works perfectly, very clean and simple. Thank you.

Comment: Of course, I am not able to accept it now. Must wait 2 minutes.

Comment: @PavanTeja Please, how to leave all digits and "."? So when I have 1.2035cm I will get 1.2035?

Comment: @user2179427 you can use `Regex rgx = new Regex("[^0-9\\.]");`

Answer (score 3):

It seem try to change "-" to '-', and better to construct the string and not replacing the char.

```
public string convert_string_to_no(string val)
    {
        string str_val = "";
        int val_len = val.Length;
        for (int i = 0; i < val_len; i++)
        {
            char myChar = Convert.ToChar(val.Substring(i, 1));
            if (char.IsDigit(myChar) && myChar == '-')
            {
                 str_val +=  myChar; 
            }
        }
        return str_val;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I perfer Linq:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
  public static string ToLimitedString(this string instance,
    string validCharacters)
  {
    // null reference checking...

    var result = new string(instance
      .Where(c => validCharacters.Contains(c))
      .ToArray());

    return result;
  }
}
```

usage:

```
var test ="Q1W2-hjkxas1-EE3R4-5T";
var limited = test.ToLimitedString("01234567890-");
Console.WriteLine(limited);
```

result:

> 12-1-34-5

[DotNetFiddle Example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DHU374)